# Quartz on Azure App Service stops working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, quartz.net, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure App Service Web App (on Free plan) to host my small project. In it I use a Quartz.Net scheduler to run task based on my rule. What I noticed is that if I don't visit web app for some amount of time (like 30-40 minutes) the Quartz stops performing it's tasks. My guess is that Azure stops the Web app if noone visits it after some amount of time, but I couldn't find any proofs of this neither in documentation, nor in description of pricing plans.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because there is a setting on Azure -> application settings called 'Always on', on FREE plan you **can't** turn it on (only on BASIC plan and above.) [image of app settings on Azure WebApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObrFt.png)

Had same issue with my web app.